# Specified method is not supported which works fine when I execute in WindowsFormsApp

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

My intention is to check if the user provided date and time is valid. I have checked the below code in `WindowsFormsApp` and it worked well there. I am working with `RPA` Automation Anywhere where I am creating a `.Net DLL` to validate date and time of inputs. When I pass the date time parameters from Automation Anywhere tool, I am getting an error "Specified method is not supported."

I am new to C#, kindly advise how I can modify the below code to solve the issue.

`strDate` value passed as '06/06/2020'
`strTime` value passed as '14:45:04' from `RPA` tool `Automation Anywhere`

```
strDate = strDate.ToString();
strTime = strTime.ToString();

        try
        {
            //Date format checks
            string[] strDateFormats = { "mm/dd/yyyy", "m/d/yyyy", "mm/d/yyyy", "m/dd/yyyy", "mm/dd/yy", "m/d/yy", "mm/d/yy", "m/dd/yy" };

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, strDateFormats,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime dt1))
                //if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, strDateFormats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt1))
                {
                strDateReturn = dt1.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
                }
            //Provided Date is invalid, set it with empty value
            else
            {
                strDateReturn = string.Empty;
            }

            //Time format checks
            string[] strTimeFormats = { "h\\:m\\:s", "H\\:m\\:s"};
            //string[] strTimeFormats = { "hh\\:mm\\:ss", "hh\\:m\\:s", "hh\\:mm\\:s", "hh\\:m\\:ss", "h\\:mm\\:ss", "h\\:m\\:s", "h\\:m\\:ss", "h\\:mm\\:s", "HH\\:mm\\:ss", "HH\\:m\\:s", "HH\\:mm\\:s", "HH\\:m\\:ss", "H\\:mm\\:ss", "H\\:m\\:s", "H\\:m\\:ss", "H\\:mm\\:s" };
            bool res = DateTime.TryParse(strTime, out DateTime dt3);

            //If res==True, the provided input is in AM/PM format and converting the same in 24 hrs format
            if (res == true)
            {
                strTime = dt3.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                strTimeReturn = strTime;
            }

            //If res==False, the provided input is in 24 hrs format but not sure if the provided time is valid
            else
            {
                if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(strTime, strTimeFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, TimeSpanStyles.None, out TimeSpan dt2))
                //if (TimeSpan.TryParse(strTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out TimeSpan dt2))
                    //if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(strTime, strTimeFormats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out TimeSpan dt2))
                    {
                    strTimeReturn = dt2.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                }
                //If invalid time is provided set it as empty
                else
                {
                    strTimeReturn = string.Empty;
                }
            }

        }
```

`

I get this error by running it
    Error with `DateTime.TryParseExact/TimeSpan.TryParseExact`

Comment: Use these formats: `string[] strTimeFormats = { "h\\:m\\:s", "H\\:m\\:s" };`. Good for `10:15:27 AM`, `10:15:27 PM`, `10:15:27`, `20:15:27`, `10:5:7 AM` etc.. And add this: `bool res = DateTime.TryParse(strTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime dt3);` (since you appear to accept date/time in the `InvariantCulture` format). The tool you import from may not use that format, though. Check `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `.CurrentUICulture` and inspect the date/time strings you actually get as input.

Comment: @Jimi          Here is the updated code `if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, strDateFormats,  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out DateTime dt1)); if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(strTime, strTimeFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, TimeSpanStyles.None, out TimeSpan dt2))`. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: If you need to add details or post new code, edit your question and update it. Don't post your code in comments. You still need to provide the actual value of `strDate`. Remember that `TryParseExact` expects that the format of the input matches **exactly** one of the formats provided. If the format of the input doesn't match any of the formats, you get a negative result.

Comment: @jimi Thank you. Have modified the question as suggested. Kindly assist further

Comment: With the input provided: `06/06/2020` and `14:45:04`, your own parsing methods return `true` for both. Or this is not the input you get or the error is somewhere else.